# Find the volume of the region which lies inside both $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $y^2+z^2=r^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the region inside two cylinders $x^2+z^2 \le r^2$ and $y^2+z^2 \le r^2$. 
I attempted this question by **combining the two inequalities** $x^2+2z^2+y^2 \le 2r^2$ and I got the bounds for $z$ which is $-\sqrt{{(2r^2-x^2-y^2)}/{2}} \le z \le \sqrt{{(2r^2-x^2-y^2)}/{2}}$. 
And I found the bound on $y$ to be $-\sqrt{(2r^2-x^2)} \le y \le \sqrt{(2r^2-x^2)}$, the bound on x is $0 \le x \le r$.
I am not sure if the above attempt is correct, if not, can anyone provide the correct way to find the bounds on z and y?

Comment: MathJax tip: `\le` will produce $\le$. For example, `$x^2 + z^2 \le r^2$` produces $x^2 + z^2 \le r^2$.

Comment: Pls go through this page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid

Comment: Also if you search the site, you should be able to find similar questions

Comment: One approach is to look at symmetries: this region can be thought of as 16 copies of the region with $x,y,z\ge 0$ and $x\le z$.  In particular, this region is bounded only by $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and planes ($x=0$, $x=z$, and $y=0$).  This is much simpler to integrate because there is only one curved boundary instead of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you visualize it carefully, you might be able to see that for fixed $y$ the cross-section is a square. Then:

$$|x| \le \sqrt{r^2 - y^2},$$
$$|z| \le \sqrt{r^2 - y^2}.$$

Then, the cross-section is a square of area $4 (r^2 - y^2)$ and the volume should be:

$$\int_{-r}^r dy 4 (r^2 - y^2) = 16 r^3/3.$$